# Error initialising MongoDB replica set in Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-replica-set

I have created a MongoDB docker container, with a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/), using this command:

```
docker run -d --name mongo -v /data/db:/data/db mongo --replSet name
```

The container starts running.

I then try to [initiate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/#rs.initiate) the replica set, using this command:

```
rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "fa07bcdd8591:27017",
    "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23
}
```

But it gives the error message "*already initialized*".

When I check the health of the replica set with the [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) command

```
rs.status()
{
    "state" : 10,
    "stateStr" : "REMOVED",
    "uptime" : 102,
    "optime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(1472680081, 1),
        "t" : NumberLong(77)
    },
    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-08-31T21:48:01Z"),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
    "code" : 93
}
```

It says the replica set config is invalid.

Comment: Have you specified any replica set configuration at all?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out sudhakar? I've been having the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

It looks you didn't specify any replica set configuration.

The [replica set initiate example](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/rs.initiate/):

```html
  rs.initiate(
   {
      _id: "myReplSet",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "mongodb0.example.net:27017" },
         { _id: 1, host : "mongodb1.example.net:27017" },
         { _id: 2, host : "mongodb2.example.net:27017" }
      ]
   }
)
```